# Python Date to EPOCH conversion

Tags: python, date, epoch

```
import time
print(int(time.mktime(time.strptime('2017-08-12T17:07:46', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))))
```

I get 1502582866 and I expect 1502557666? Any help is welcome

Comment: I think that `mktime` is being interpreted as being in your local time, which I'm guessing is Pacific. If you want 1502557666, you need the time zone of the input to `mktime` to be UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Paul is correct: according to the documentation, `mktime` will take a `struct_time` in *local time* and convert it to *seconds since the epoch*, which has no timezones nor daylight savings.

So, your initial time of:

```
`2017-08-12T17:07:46`
```

becomes:

```
1502582866 ==> `GMT: Sunday, August 13, 2017 12:07:46 AM`
```

which is correct.

If you are wondering how to correctly convert back, you would use `localtime`:

```
import time
epoch_time = 1502582866
time_string = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(epoch_time))
print time_string
>> 2017-08-12T17:07:46
```

Also see a sample in action here: https://eval.in/845075